# HTML post request (login form)

Tags: java, c#, post, authentication, request

I need to login into a website. I tried to archive this by sending the right POST request. I can gather the required data (two security tokens, and a cookie) which seems to work without any problem. But the final login process does not work - but sadly: I have no clue where to find the problem because the server simply redirects me to the login page without any hints.
This is the current state of my approach:

```
URL url = new URL("SERVER");
Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
params.put("security_token", security_token);
params.put("login_ticket", login_ticket);
params.put("loginname", "USERNAME");
params.put("password", "PASSWORD");
params.put("login", "Login");

StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
    if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
    postData.append('=');
    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
}
byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);


conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = conn.getHeaderFields();
```

I have already tried to solve this problem with C#. The code below works fine, so I simply tried to "translate" it into java.

```
string cookie = "COOKIEVALUE";
request.Host = new Uri("SERVER");
//request.PostData.Add("Cookie", cookies[0]);
request.PostData.Add("loginname", "USERNAME");
request.PostData.Add("password", "PW");
request.PostData.Add("login_ticket","269ba20ad5a6f1a0219a3a333d3a5997");
request.PostData.Add("security_token", "ZHfyszNSuMrN8Xw80Pudka+5cZB20j+or+JWXCWzVPg=");

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
try
{
    request.SendRequest(cookie);
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response == null)
            throw new WebException();
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            }
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException)
{
    throw;
}
```

...

and the SendRequest method's code

```
public void SendRequest(string cookieValue,byte[] buffer = null)
{
    _webRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(Host);
    _webRequest.Method = "POST";
    _webRequest.ContentType = ContentType;

    _webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    var cookie = new Cookie("Seminar_Session", cookieValue);
    cookie.Domain = Host.Host;
    _webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);

    string postString = "";
    foreach (var item in PostData)
    {
        postString += item.Key + "=" + item.Value + "&";
    }

    if (postString.Length > 0)
        postString = postString.Remove(postString.Length - 1, 1);

    byte[] postBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);

    _webRequest.ContentLength = postBuffer.Length;
    if (buffer != null) _webRequest.ContentLength += buffer.Length;

    using (var requestStream = _webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
        if (buffer != null) requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        requestStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to get the Java code working. Is there anything which I did obviously wrong? Sadly I can not further work with the C# code an do now need a working solution in Java. So, how can I solve this problem with the not working java version?

Edit: In the end I used the apache components for these request.

```
    String security_token;
    String login_ticket;

    //setup configuration
    RequestConfig globalConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.BEST_MATCH).build();

    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCookieStore(_cookieStore);

    //send request to get login data


    Document source;
    security_token = "TOKEN";
    login_ticket = "TICKET";
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.studip.uni-goettingen.de/");

    // Request parameters and other properties.
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("security_token", security_token));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login_ticket", login_ticket));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginname", _credentials.getUserName()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", _credentials.getPassword()));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

    //Execute the login post request and get the response.
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost, context);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 0):

They are using some hash function to generate those security tokens. In most cases this hashes use the complete form, including the fields in it, to make the hash. Your problem may be that you are not using it and so the hash won't be the same. If you reload the page you will see the login_ticket change because of the same reason.

Comment: I don't think, that this is the real problem, as the C# code has the exactly same approach as the Java code: Firstly send one request to gather the tokens, then send a post request to perform the login. As the C# code works, there must be a problem in the Java implementation.